# Not able to make the local manifest file as default for repo sync

Tags: android, synchronization, manifest, repo

After downloading the `Nexus 5x` android source code from google, I want to integrate our code to it. So, I created a local manifest file under `.repo/local_manifests/local_manifest.xml`.

I ran `repo init -m .repo/local_manifests/local_manifest.xml` and got the following error.

> fatal: manifest '.repo/local_manifests/local_manifest.xml' not available
>   fatal: manifest .repo/local_manifests/local_manifest.xml not found

Answer (score 0):

`repo init -m some_path/manifest.xml` would try to read .repo/manifests/some_path/manifest.xml, which would of course fail because the file does not exist. I have no idea how .repo/local_manifests/ works, but I'm sure if you use the full path instead of a relative path, it'll work well.

Answer (score 0):

`.repo/local_manifests/` is a location for additional remotes and projects. Manifests in this directory are loaded and processed after the primary manifest, in alphabetical order.

local manifests are good for specifying alternate base paths within a manifest.

Although not asked here, but relevant: `./repo/local_manifest.xml` is no longer supported.

Reference repo docs:
https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/git-repo/blob/main/docs/manifest-format.md#Local-Manifests